# Classification of $E(\mathbb{R})$ when $E$ is given by $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ given by the equation
$$
y^2=x^3+ax+b,\quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

I know that depending on whether $x^3+ax+b$ has one or three real roots, then $E(\mathbb{R})$ is either $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\times C_2$, respectively. I know a proof from the latter parts of Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

However, this problem of classifying the subgroup of real points also is Exercise 1 of Section VI.1 of Koblitz's text *Number Theory and Cryptography*, which assumes very little mathematical prerequisites, and briefly states that $E\simeq\mathbb{C}/L$, where $L$ is some lattice, without really giving any details of the Weierstrass function, and then sketches that this is isomorphic to a torus.

My question is, is there a "very elementary" way to classify the group of real points $E(\mathbb{R})$, in this case where the coefficients of the elliptic curve are real, using only tools from a one semester undergrad algebra course, as this is roughly the mathematical requirements of said book?

Comment: I haven't thought this through carefully, so it may lead nowhere (or be outright incorrect), but perhaps it's enough to note that $E(\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with the subgroup of $E(\mathbb{C})$ which are invariant under the (functorial) complex conjugation action. Provided that the isomorphism $E(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}/L$ is equivariant w.r.t complex conjugation, it would remain to identify what the fixed points of $\mathbb{C}/L$ can look like.